# django-cors-headers not working at all

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

Well, initially I had forgotten the **middleware class** but after adding it just worked fine ( It was a week ago ).

Now, I am back to my workstation and I find it again not working.

The `ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN` headers are not at all being set.

I have tried all that is, placing the middleware at top, before `CommonMiddleware` but it just doesn't work.

This is my **setting.py** file :

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
]

# if DEBUG:
#     INSTALLED_APPS += 'corsheaders',
#     MIDDLEWARE = ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', ]
# else:
#     MIDDLEWARE = []

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = DEBUG
```

This is the response I am getting :

```
Date: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 09:35:09 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.14+
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 146
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is included in the response only if `origin` header is present in the request.

Browser adds this header automatically, so you shouldn't see CORS errors on the web page that uses your API.

For me this request returned no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:80/status`

And this one does:

`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "origin: *" localhost:80/status`

The answer on GitHub page:
https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/issues/438

Answer (score -2):

```
# Cors headers

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```